# displaying text from .txt file in kivy

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to make an app that displays text from a .txt file.
Unfortunately when i set a StringProperty, Label binded to it doesn't change. Its possible for me to just print it in the console. Could you give me some advice?

python code:

```
class notatnik(Screen):
    notatnik_plik = open(r"notatnik.txt","r")
    #prints the file to the console(works)
    print(notatnik_plik.read())
    
    fileoutput = StringProperty(notatnik_plik.read())
    notatnik_plik.close()
```

kv code:

```
<notatnik>:
    name: "screen_notatnik"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: root.fileoutput
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
```

result:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5APrf.png)

.txt file is a simple hello_world

Comment: Try removing the `print()` statement.

Comment: @JohnAnderson it works now. thank you.